# IE is aborting elements when the page is redirected

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect

I have something weird going on with IE (don't we all), in that when a page on my website is redirected via php header or javascript code it will abort one or two of the elements like a a js file, css or a ajax request and will cause the page to reload the elements again.

If I hit the same page direct, it will load as intended.

Has anyone else come across this error?

Thanks in advance for your input.